# Get BoundingBox of ONLY visible area of map in osmdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid, bounding-box

I am using osmdroid version 4 and I want to have BoundingBox of visible map. It seems that `MapView.getBoundingBox` method returns bounding box of all tiles that are visible or partially visible. Take a look at this picture:

[image]

Black rectangles are tiles, red rectangle with rounded corners is  device display.

I want to have only diagonal area shown by green line. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are mistaken. getBoundingBox() returns the lat/long boundaries of what is visible on the screen. The code will take the pixel x,y value of the two corners and covert that into lat/long and that is what is used. It is not "snapped" to actual map tiles. The result of getBoundingBox() should return the area of the red box.

Comment: I put marker at the bottom right of visible map and that is invisible I have to move map to see that marker so I think you are wrong. I will test it again!

Comment: If you are using the ItemizedIconOverlay, make sure you are setting your Hotspot correctly.